# I have a water heater with a wireless transmitter for changing the temp, how can I sniff the commands sent between them?

Tags: sniffer

Long story short I'm automating a lot of my stuff at home and as part of that I'd like to be able to replicate the commands sent to my unit (https://www.rinnai.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/mc_503rc_operating_instructions.pdf) so I can then use them in automations to automatically adjust the temperature based on certain factors.

I did something similar with my ducted aircon, but they have an iphone app and an API so I was able to use Charles as a http proxy to see what the commands were.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on how the wireless part works - for non smart controllers, it's often just a generic radio signal rather than using something like http or piggybacking on WiFi.

Comment: Yep I think it's probably just generic, it talks about LIPD in the install docs (Low Interference Potential Devices) but I'm not familiar with that at all

Comment: of course you can use a software defined radio to spy on it, but sending commands might be more difficult.

Comment: Right ok, that sounds like too hard basket to me!